# Tampermonkey Javascript script not entering text and clicking button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a script that automatically navigates from one website to another upon button click, enters text into a form field and clicks a button on the second website. However, the script is not working as intended and is not entering the text or clicking the button.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Attempts to find the form element with the name attribute "url" and enters the text "Test"
        var urlInput = document.getElementsByName("url")[0];
        if(urlInput) {
            urlInput.value = "Test";
        }

        // Attempts to find the element with the class "submit" and clicks it
        var submitBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0];
        if(submitBtn) {
            submitBtn.click();
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

I have added a setTimeout of 3 seconds to ensure that the website has sufficient time to load before attempting to access the form elements.
Also, I have added a check to see if the form element and the button are found and trying to access them only if they are found.

Comment: The script should be available inside the other website/webpage. Can you check if the javascript code you've written is getting loaded in the other webpage by Tampermonkey as well after redirecting?
Also instead of a setTimeout, use `document.readyStateChange`.

Comment: I tried to make a console on the other website that logs everything but it did not work. How would i properly load the script on the other website?

Comment: Did you try changing the timeOut to onReadyStateChange? Also, it might be an issue with tamperMonkey extension where-in your script might not be loading. If they have a github community, I would request you to raise an issue there as well. Hope my comment helped

Comment: I've changed timeOut to onReadyStateChange method, however, the issue persists. Tampermonkey shows that the script is running on Site 1, but not on Site 2. I will ask on GitHub. Thanks!